# Reporting Services Expression for Week of Year

Tags: asp.net, datetime, reporting

I have a Report that I send a parameter to as 'WeekStart'. This is based on a selection a user makes on a datepicker.

I'm using the following to extract the week of the year:

`=DatePart("ww", Parameters!WeekStart.Value)`

The problem I'm having is that when I pick the day 03/01/2012 (dd/MM/yyyy format), the week of the year is returned as 9, which would technically be true had the date been 03/01/2012 with a dateformat of MM/dd/yyyy.

I've tried using CDate, FormatDateString etc but nothing seems to be working. I either get #Error or it returns as the 9th week of the year.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
use YourDatabase
go

set dateformat dmy
go
```

That will set the date format for your database, and that should get your `DATEPART` function working as expected.

[SET DATEFORMAT (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't work. I also tried changing the shortdate format in regedit so that they're all the same. But it all still displays wrong.